# I succesfully installed scikit-flow by using pip but somehow it doesn't work when I import and use it

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, tensorflow, importerror

I've already installed scikitlearn the other day and The code which I tried to execute is as follows.

```
import skflow
from sklearn import datasets, metrics

iris = datasets.load_iris()
classifier = skflow.TensorFlowLinearClassifier(n_classes=3)
classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
score = metrics.accuracy_score(classifier.predict(iris.data),     iris.target)
print("Accuracy: %f" % score)
```

Above code is the one I found in Githubgist page.
And the rusult was

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-16b804f4d3b1> in <module>()
----> 1 import skflow
      2 from sklearn import datasets, metrics
      3 
      4 iris = datasets.load_iris()
      5 classifier = skflow.TensorFlowLinearClassifier(n_classes=3)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     16 import pkg_resources as pkg_rs
     17 import numpy as np
---> 18 import tensorflow as tf
     19 
     20 from skflow.io import *

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     21 from __future__ import print_function
     22 
---> 23 from tensorflow.python import *

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     43 _default_dlopen_flags = sys.getdlopenflags()
     44 sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags | ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
---> 45 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     46 sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags)
     47 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     26                 fp.close()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper
     30 else:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in swig_import_helper()
     22         if fp is not None:
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:
     26                 fp.close()

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I started coding very recently so I can't handle with this problem at all..
What does 'wrong architecture' mean here??
Hope anyone answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a wrong version of tensorflow installed.
Wrong architecture in this case probably means that you installed linux version of TF on your OS X.

I would recommend uninstalling both tensorflow and skflow and then running this command (for OS X with Python2.7):

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade six
sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.8.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl
```

Skflow is now part of the TensorFlow, so you can use by importing `import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow` instead of `import skflow`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. I tried to uninstall tensorflow by pip. And the result was like...                              
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/external/__init__.py'

Comment: But when I checked packages which are already installed,there is no such packages named tensorflow. This means I successfully uninstalled tensorflow, I guess. I'm not so sure though...

Comment: hmm, I finished installing tensorflow again and excuted the same code I posted,but the same error has occured again...

Comment: seems the package already installed is automatically uninstalled when we install it more than once. Then I replaced the code from 'import skflow' to  import 'tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow' but it didn't work.. I wonder code itself is wrong..?

Comment: I ran another code but ended up with the same error... Seriously,what is wrong..?

Comment: You should either uninstall previous install and install the new one, OR start a clean conda environment following [this instruction](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#change-environments-activate-deactivate).

Comment: conda uninstall tensorflow
Fetching package metadata: SSL verification error Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
.SSL verification error Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
.SSL verification error Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
.SSL verification error Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
.
Error: no packages found to remove from environment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7

Comment: I installed conda and another problem.. Now I cannot use pip nor jupyter notebook..

Comment: I created pyenv and reinstalled python2,3. Using pip,I installed matplotlib and numpy in this order
And then pandas
sudo installed six(upgrade)
sudo pip installed tensorflow
scipy,scikit-learn,sympy,biopython

Comment: Then I tried the following code     import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
from sklearn import datasets, metrics

iris = datasets.load_iris()
classifier = skflow.TensorFlowLinearClassifier(n_classes=3)
classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
score = metrics.accuracy_score(classifier.predict(iris.data),     iris.target)
print("Accuracy: %f" % score)

Comment: You need to install sklearn as well - pip install sklearn because you are using sklearn's datasets and metrics in the example.